# How to train keras model using Google Cloud TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, keras

Theoretically, we are able to train Tensorflow backed **Keras model** on any platform that supports Tensorflow. However, I can't seem to find any info on how to do it in Google's documentation https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/.

Answer (score 0):

We have an example in the TPU repository here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/experimental/cifar_keras/cifar_keras.py

Comment: Thanks, it seems the example still have a fair amount of Tensorflow content in it. Such the loss functions and optimizers. Also, in the example, Keras is imported from 'tf.contrib'. I know Keras is developed by Google's team but is that the recommended way to use Keras now?

Comment: I am also trying to re-use my keras inference code in TPU, and it seems like there is no easy way.

Comment: did you find a way? I'm trying to use `tf.keras.applications`' models alongside this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/08_image/flowersmodeltpu/model.py).

I just replaced the `cnn_model` with a function that imports the `tf.keras.applications` models. But I get the error **NotImplementedError: Operation of type ReadVariableOp  (block1_conv1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp) is not supported on the TPU for inference. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph. Make sure your variables are using variable_scope.**