# How to train Tensorflow with Cloud TPUs from my local machine?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to do this tutorial(https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu), but using my own provisioned TPU. But when I try to change to my own TPU I cannot resolve the TPU cluster, i.e., I get a timeout when I run the cell:

```py
tpu_addr = f"{MY_TPU_IP}:8470" # os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'], if running colab's TPU
resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu=f'grpc://{tpu_addr}')
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
```

`MY_TPU_IP` I get from the TPU that I create in https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/tpus.

### Notes:

1. Before I run the cell I authenticate against GCP with the account that created the TPU running:

```py
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

2. I am aware of this question ins SO: [How to train keras model using Google Cloud TPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771723/how-to-train-keras-model-using-google-cloud-tpu).

But the answer does not address this problem, as it points to a code example that requires to solve my problem (how to resolve the TPU cluster IP). Moreover, the answer is for TensorFlow v1 (which I could port to v2 myself if it would solve my problem in the first place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. 
The IP in the TPU dashboard is an "Internal IP." The only way to access it is through a Jump server in the same data center as the TPU, i.e., SSH Tunneling.

Here is an article describing the whole process in detail: [Train neural networks faster with tpu from your laptop](https://medium.com/solving-the-human-problem/train-neural-networks-faster-with-googles-tpu-from-your-laptop-58838873b29c)

But the idea is:

1. Create a TPU
2. Create a Jump Server
3. Create a Storage Bucket
4. Run this command to create the SSH Tunnel: `ssh $USER@$JUMP -L 2000:$TPU:8470`
5. Train your model.