# Run TensorFlow 2.x on local machine TPU cores, or restricted to the Cloud?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow2.0, tpu

Is it possible to use TensorFlow on the TPU cores of a local machine or is TF restricted to only cloud services, i.e. Collab or [creating one on the cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59963646/how-to-train-tensorflow-with-cloud-tpus-from-my-local-machine)?

Answer (score 1):

TPU cores are only available on Google's Cloud TPUs, so you can only access them through GCP or Colab.